# Form Validation Loop to check all text and select not empty

Tags: javascript

```
function validatForm(){
    $("#add_form input[type=text]").each(function() {
       if(this.value == null || this.value == '') {
            $(this).addClass("alert_focus");
            alert('Required Field Cannot Be Emmpty')
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 500);
        }
    });


<form id="add_form">
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Select*</th>
      <th>Field A*</th>
      <th>Field B*</th>
      <th>Field C*</th>
    <tr>
    </tr>
      <td><select class="select" name="select1">
          <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="a_field1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="b_field1" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="c_field1" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><select class="select" name="select2">
          <option>Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="a_field2" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="b_field2" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="c_field2" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><select class="select" name="select3">
          <option>Please Select</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      </td>
      <td><input type="text" name="a_field3" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="b_field3" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="c_field3" /></td>
    </tr>
    ............ and so on.
</table>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return validatForm()">Submit</a>
<input type="hidden" value="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The above works well so far for input[type="text"].
Is there anyway I can check if any of the select is empty/not_selected and identify that element?

I have tried:

```
$(".select").each(function() {
if (!$(".select option:selected").length) {
    alert('Required Field Cannot Be Emmpty')
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 500);
}
});
return false;
```

But it doesn't seems to work.
Your help is appreciated :)
Many Thanks

**With the help from RobG, here is the script that works:**

```
<script>
function validatForm(){
    $("#add_cat input[type=text]").each(function() {
        if(!this.value) {
            $(this).addClass("alert_focus");
            alert('Required Field Cannot Be Emmpty');
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top }, 500);    
        }
    });
    $('#add_cat select').each(function(i, select){
        if (select.selectedIndex <= 0) {
            alert('Please select an option');
        }
    return false;
    });
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate over the select elements, the selector is: `'select'`.

jQuery's [*each*](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is different to the built–in Array *forEach* method, the parameters are *index*, *element* rather than *element*, *index* which might be expected.

You can compare the select's value to '' (empty string), however since nearly all browsers will select the first option by default, a better strategy is to set the first option to the default selected and check that, e.g.

```
<select name="...">
  <option value="" selected>Select one
  <option value="one">one
</select>
```

then:

```
$('select').each(function(i, select){
  if (select.selectedIndex <= 0) {
    alert('Please select an option');
  }
});
```

The selected index will be -1 if no option is selected, that shouldn't happen often but needs to be accommodated.

Comment: Thanks. It works great and I can move from there. may I know what the "i" in your script is for? => i, select

Comment: Per jQuery documentation and the answer, the first argument *each* passes to the callback is the index of the element in the collection, the second argument is the element itself. You don't care about the index (*i*), but you need a parameter in the first location to get to the second, the element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use element selector(`select`) not class selector(`.select`), then you can see whether it have a value instead of checking whether there is a selected option

```
$("select").each(function () {
    if (!$(this).val().length) {
        alert('Required Field Cannot Be Emmpty')
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);
    }
});
```